# express.js global try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a rest server on Node JS with Express.

I'm trying to wrap all my endpoints in try\catch block, so a central point of error will response back to the sender with details.
My problem that response (res instance) is alive for each of the endpoints methods, but I don't know how to make it global.

```
try {
    app.get('/webhook', function (req, res) {
        webhook.register(req, res);
    });

    app.get('/send', function (req, res) {
        sendAutoMessage('1004426036330995');
    });

    app.post('/webhook/subscribe', function (req, res) {
        webhook.subscribe("test");
    });

    app.post('/webhook/unsubscribe', function (req, res) {
        webhook.unsubscribe("test");
    });
} catch (error) {
    //response to user with 403 error and details
}
```

Comment: @epascarello could you direct me to example ?

Comment: End your response manually using `response.end`. This will end your response

Comment: You can't rely on a global if you have any async operations (which you presumably do) because your server can be processing many requests at once.  Also a high level try/catch won't catch errors that happen in an async callback.  For something that works like node.js, your approach is flawed.

Comment: @jfriend00 how would you suggest to have a central error handling ?

Comment: @AsafNevo have you [read the fine manual](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)?

Comment: You can centralize the display of errors into common functions, but you can't centralize the actual error handling.  There is no substitute for catching an exception near where it occurs and handling it properly (such as cleaning up resources).  Promises will help you do that with async operations because they catch all exceptions and turn them into promise rejections and propagate errors for you.

Comment: @robertklep I did, but didn't understand how to I "throw" and error that will get to that code

Answer (score 16):

There is a library ([express-async-errors](https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors)) which could suit your needs.
This enables you to write async route handlers without wrapping the statements in try/catch blocks and catch them with global error handler.
To make this work you must:
1. Install the `express-async-errors` package
2. Import package (before the routes)
3. Set up global express error handler
4. Write async route handlers ([More info about this](https://strongloop.github.io/strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/))

Example usage:

```
import express from 'express';
import 'express-async-errors';

const app = express();

// route handlers must be async
app.get('/webhook', async (req, res) => {
    webhook.register(req, res);
});

app.get('/send', async (req, res) => {
    sendAutoMessage('1004426036330995');
});

app.post('/webhook/subscribe', async (req, res) => {
    webhook.subscribe("test");
});

app.post('/webhook/unsubscribe', async (req, res) => {
    webhook.unsubscribe("test");
});

// Global error handler - route handlers/middlewares which throw end up here
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    // response to user with 403 error and details
});
```

Answer (score 13):

`try catch` can not catch error asynchronously.
This will work:

```
app.get('/webhook', function (req, res) {
        try { 
          //enter code here
        } catch (error) {
          // something here
        }
    });
```

But it is local and not the best way.

Good way is make error-handling middleware function. It is global. You need to define it after all `app.use()` and routes calls.

```
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // This is error handler
    });
```

You can send the html page with details of error to client as usual.

Also, by default, Express have built-in error handler. The error will be written to the client with stack trace (It does not work in production mode).

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date. `try catch` now can catch async errors (ie it can handle promise rejections).

Comment: @JemarJones `try catch` could *only* catch async error with async/await syntax, so anyway is useless in this scenario

Comment: @mdn Fair point, the answer should probably mention it with that caveat though

Answer (score 1):

this kind of try catch will not catch errors when some third function is called do the best solution will use global exception handler

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
     res.status(err.status || 500);
     res.end();
});
```

also you have to use promises in your end point handlers
that will catch errors in any scope